# How to get Webpack Dev Server to display images stored locally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I migrated a project I have been working on to Webpack 2 and this has been kind of a headache. But I have gotten my project to preview using Webpack dev server, except it won't show my image. All I get is this error in the browser console `GET http://localhost:8080/logo.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

and in MacOS Console:

```
   ERROR in ./js/components/Global/Menu.jsx Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'logo.jpg' in '/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/js/components/Global'
```

This is my Webpack configuration:

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      context: __dirname + "/app",

      entry: {
        app: "./js/app.js",
        javascript: "./js/app.js",
        html: "./index.html",
      },

      output: {
        //output.path: "[name].js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist",
        filename: "[name].js"
      },

      resolve: {
        alias: { 'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount' },
        extensions: [ '*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
        modules:[__dirname, './app/js', 'node_modules'],
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            include: [
              path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
            ],
            loaders: ["babel-loader"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: ["file-loader?name=[name].[ext]"],
          },
          {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
            include : path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
            loader  : 'url-loader?limit=30000&name=images/[name].[ext]'
          }
        ],
      },
    }
```

The migration has broken multiple images but heres one and I can use is it as a base to fix the others:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

import Logo from "logo.jpg";

export default class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Menu' id='Menu'>
        <img src={Logo}></img>
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>  <Link to='/about'>Clothing</Link>  <Link to='/Cart'>Cart</Link>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Should I use `url('logo.jpg')`? Why is the dev server not finding the images and displaying them?

**EDIT**

Tried with:

```
let img = new Image();
img.src = require('logo.jpg');
```

and `<img src={img.src}>`, but it gives me the same error.

Comment: `/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/js/components/Global` is that where your images live ?

Comment: @realseanp yes..I dont know why it's not finding them..

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you not doing `<img src="./logo.jpg">`?

Comment: Also, your import paths in the components should be relative to the location of the images. As your images are in Global, the relative paths in your components should point to the images accordingly. Unless you setup an alias to make it easier.

Comment: @hazardous using `<img src=.?logo.jpg>` was giving me the same error so looking for answers I found that React Dev Server can't read file like this? This just has me completely confused at this point..

Comment: You don't have to do anything special to make images work. i would double check the relative paths between my components and the images. Could you share and bare minimum repro code?

Comment: @hazardous Which are the relative paths you are referring to between my components and the images?

Comment: It's not very clear where menu.jsx is in relation to the Global folder.

Comment: @hazardous It's in the global folder as well so this Global folder has menu.jsx and images.

Comment: if menu.jsx and logo.png are in the same folder, you'll wanna `import Logo from './logo.png'`, not 'logo.png'. it would appear you have no alias setup for that location.

Comment: put a minimal repro code somewhere to debug this further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your webpack configuration doesn't declare explicitly [`output.publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) setting. A basic configuration might be like:

```
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
```

***Further consideration:*** since your `logo.jpg` lives in the same directory as your component, why not importing it with a `./` relative path?

```
import Logo from "./logo.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should review this guide:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/

you use old format config for webpack1, config for webpack2 below;

```js
module: {
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
    ],
    use: ["babel-loader"],
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [{
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
           name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
    }],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    include : path.join(__dirname, 'app'),
    use: [{
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
           limit: 30000,
           name: '[name].[ext]'
        }
    }]
  }
],
  },
```

Comment: Fixed this..but still getting the same error..I wonder where exactly is it looking for images..

Comment: `node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server` ..I should have added that in my terminal I also get this :`ERROR in ./js/components/Global/Menu.jsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'logo.jpg' in '/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/js/components/Global'`

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the issue. You are not specifying the correct path for the image when importing. Try adding an alias for the image folder

```
resolve: {
    alias: { 
      'react/lib/ReactMount': 'react-dom/lib/ReactMount',
      images: '/Users/user1/Documents/AAA/app/js/components/Global', // absolute path to images folder
    },
    extensions: [ '*', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules:[__dirname, './app/js', 'node_modules'],
  },
```

Then import your images like this:

```
import Logo from 'images/logo.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

specifying absolute publicPath worked for me. [Reference](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/55)

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
    include: path.join(__dirname, '/app'),
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      outputPath: path.join(__dirname, '/app/dist'),,
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      emitFile: true,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually just have to add that image inside the `public` folder and you can directly use it as `<img src="logo.png" />`